# How to make bootstrap column width based on longest column for each row?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

## The issue

I have a list with two columns. My issue is that I want the left column to start where the based on where the first columns longest column is ending. At the moment it starts right after the first.

What do I have to do to make the second columns start where the longest first column ends?

[image: How it looks vs Result I want]

*How it looks vs Result I want*

### What I have tried

I have tried to use row-fluid with *col* on the first column and *col my-auto* on the last column. It does looks right at a middle sized screen.
But on smaller screens like cellphones the text is going over each other. And on larger screens the text is just way to far from each other.

*Snippet from code in The code section*

```
<div class="row fluid">
 <div class="col">
   <label id="key" for="object.key"><b>{{object.key}}:</b></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col my-auto">
   <label id="object.key">{{object.value}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to read the documentation at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/ but couldn't locate what would fix my problem.

#### The code

I have made a simple *Two Column Array* component in Angular. I use bootstrap for styling. The idea is to show a list of information inside a card dynamically.

**HTML**

```
<ng-container>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-fluid" *ngFor="let object of ListObjects" ng-class-odd='odd'>
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="mt-1">
            <label id="key" for="object.key"><b>{{object.key}}:</b></label>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-1">
          <label id="object.key">{{object.value}}</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

**Ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ListTwoColumnObject } from '@models/list-two-column';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-two-column-list',
  templateUrl: './two-column-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./two-column-list.component.css']
})
export class TwoColumnListComponent {
  @Input() ListObjects: ListTwoColumnObject[];
  constructor() { }
}
```

**TwoColumnObject**

```
export class ListTwoColumnObject {
  key: any;
  value: any;

  constructor(key: any, value: any){
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

**Example of creating list**

```
const objList = Array<ListTwoColumnObject>();
 objList.push(new ListTwoColumnObject('Fakturanr.', invoice.invoiceNr));
 objList.push(new ListTwoColumnObject('Betalt', convertBool.transform(invoice.isPaid)));
 objList.push(new ListTwoColumnObject('Ordre opprettet', 
 datePipe.transform(invoice.orderDate,'yyyy.MM.dd')));
```

Comment: Rather than using Bootstrap columns, is there a disadvantage to using a table to display your data? `<tr> <th scope="row">Fakturanr.:</th> <td>100</td> </tr>`

Comment: Sorry, I don't actually know. But will a table wrap the columns under each other if the screen gets smaller? I want to avoid having a vertical scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To respond to your comment, “…will a table wrap the columns under each other if the screen gets smaller? I want to avoid having a vertical scroll.” — no, a table will not put one row beneath another to fit — tables just get smaller, but you only have two columns of data, and if your example is representative of the data you want to display, you should be okay on even an old smartphone with a 320px wide display.

As for avoiding a vertical scroll, if your content exceeds the screen height, then the display will scroll.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" lang="no">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table class="table table-borderless">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Fakturanr.:</th>
                                <td>100</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Betalt:</th>
                                <td>Ja</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Ordre opprettet:</th>
                                <td>2021.01.06</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Forfalls Dato:</th>
                                <td>2021.01.16</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Opprettet av:</th>
                                <td>edit</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Ordre type:</th>
                                <td>Oppgjort for sent</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Beløp:</th>
                                <td>450</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Innbetalt:</th>
                                <td>-450</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Rest beløp:</th>
                                <td>0</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```